Repeated x87 fnstenv yields cleared instruction pointer after arbitrary time
I have a program that calls the x87 instruction fnstenv multiple times per second and with only the occasional floating point computation being executed (in periods of multiple seconds apart), I had originally expected all data written by fnstenv to be identical between those floating point computations.
However, at some point I observe that the x87 instruction and data pointers are cleared. And the duration from the last floating point computation until this happens seems unpredictable. I have not read anything conclusive about such behavior in the Intel documentation of fnstenv.
So my question is: Can I not rely at all on these pointers to be stored "correctly" without pending x87 exception, or why do they get reset after some arbitrary time or fnstenv invocation?
As a demonstration, I have written a small test program. On my system with Linux 6.10 and an AMD Ryzen 7, it will end its loop after anywhere from just 2 to 500,000 iterations. I would at least have expected the instruction pointer not to be cleared arbitrarily but to behave in a deterministic way.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint32_t fpenv[7];

    printf("main() is at 0x%08x\n", (void *)&main);

    // perform some x87 operation to update x87 instruction pointer
    __asm__("fldz\n\t");
    
    fpenv[3] = 1;     // force initial loop iteration
    for (long count = 0; fpenv[3] != 0; count++)
    {
        /* read and store the x87 environment */
        __asm__ __volatile__ ("fnstenv\t%0" : "=m" (fpenv));
        /* print the x87 instruction pointer to the console */
        printf("%d: fip=0x%08x cs=0x%08x\n", count, fpenv[3], fpenv[4]);
    }
    return 0;
}

Compile with gcc test-fnstenv.c -o test-fnstenv
Output:
main() is at 0x5d52917d
0: fip=0x5d5291c6 cs=0x01ee0023
1: fip=0x5d5291c6 cs=0x01ee0023
2: fip=0x5d5291c6 cs=0x01ee0023
3: fip=0x5d5291c6 cs=0x01ee0023
[...]
<n-1>: fip=0x5d5291c6 cs=0x01ee0023
<n  >: fip=0x00000000 cs=0x00000000


Do the moments when fip gets cleared correspond to the times when the thread had been interrupted by the kernel?

@user555045: You're suggesting an FP context switch happened right before the fnstenv, after the last x87 instruction from this thread?  If the kernel doesn't restore that part of the FP environment then yeah that could explain it.  (Linux uses xsave/xrstor or one of the variants like xsaveopt.)

@user555045: Just an interrupt and returning to the same user-space context shouldn't normally result in an FPU save/restore (instead only GP integer), although it could if the kernel code used kernel_fpu_begin() inside the interrupt handler, e.g. to do some accelerated crypto or software RAID5/6.  But that's unlikely, perhaps more likely is RCU run_on or something else that force this core to switch to another task.  Linux uses "eager" FPU save/restore so it doesn't matter if the new task uses the FPU or SIMD or not.  Even switching to a kernel thread or IRQ bottom half might trigger save

Thanks to your discussion, I now tried out my test program pinned to a single isolated CPU core (while having both thread siblings isolated), and that did the trick! Apparently it is not the CPU which looses this part of the FP environment, it is the Linux kernel (scheduler or interrupts) where these values are getting cleared! It helps a lot knowing this. BTW, can we proceed with an answer to this topic? I am new to posting questions on SO.

Comment in arch/x86/kernel/fpu/core.c says: "AMD K7/K8 and later CPUs up to Zen don't save/restore FDP/FIP/FOP unless an exception is pending."

@jester: Thank you, this now fully explains it. You should add this as the answer. And just to confirm this, I ran the test program on an Intel N3150 with Linux 6.8 and no more clearing of the FIP!

Looks like it came from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=18bd057b1408cd110ed23281533430cfc2d52091 originally.

@ThomasReitmayr You can post an answer to your own question outlining the solution you found.
